# Getting a data attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the *data-shareurl* from the link below for use in jQuery but for some reason when I put the variable into an alert it is always undefined. Can anyone tell me what I've got wrong? Thanks.
I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmdzvLab/2/)

Html

```
<a title="" class="fancybox" data-shareurl="www.google.com" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" title="" /></a>
```

jQuery

```
 var shareurl = $(this).attr('data-shareurl'); //Get this url
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({

   beforeShow: function() {
     this.title = '<div class="addthis addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "><a href="' + this.href + '" addthis:url="' + this.href + '" addthis:title="' + this.title + '" class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a></div>';

     alert(shareurl); //see the variable


   },

   afterShow: function() {
     addthis.toolbox(
       $(".addthis").get()
     );
   },
   helpers: {
     title: {
       type: 'inside'
     }
   }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `this` as a selector. I assume that this code is outside the function `$('.fancybox')...`

Why not use the `id` or `class` as a selector.

```
var shareurl = $('.fancybox').attr('data-shareurl'); //Get this url
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).data('shareurl'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="" class="fancybox" data-shareurl="www.google.com" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" title="" /></a>
```

Hope this will help you.